# NullPointerException in transactionAdviser (Spring boot application)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-bean

I am stuck with a strange exception while developing a Spring Boot Application. I browsed a lot but couldn't find much to the rescue. Here is what I have:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.webstore.web.WebstoreWebApplication.main(WebstoreWebApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-584.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:249) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:988) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor(ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java:46) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$612e1225.CGLIB$transactionAdvisor$2(<generated>) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$612e1225$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$85e1d6f0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$612e1225.transactionAdvisor(<generated>) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-20160727.145112-33.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

The project was run without errors and worked correctly. I did not make any changes in code and then in one moment I got this exception.

Here is my JpaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories({
        "com.webstore.common.repository.jpa",
        "com.webstore.web.repository.jpa"
})
public class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String datasourceUsername;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String datasourcePassword;
    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String datasourceDriverClassName;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;

    @Bean
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(datasourceDriverClassName);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(datasourceUrl);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(datasourceUsername);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.webstore");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, hibernateDialect);
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/oler117/oler-web-store

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a reliance on snapshot versioning in your pom.xml .This means you will pull any recent releases which may not be fully bug free. If you look in your error message you will see

```
spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160727.140415-585.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

This is a version built today which might not be fully stable. Instead change your pom to use the current general availability version for stability

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in non-stable version.